# Redrawing raster layer after file changed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I'm trying to find a way to redraw a raster layer after the original source file has been changed in QGIS 3.2+. However, it redraws only sometimes (~10%), which means there is some deep caching that I cannot clear. In addition, if I duplicate the layer or add it again by double-clicking the file browser, the new layer is rendered properly, but the old one stays with the outdated data. What I did so far both in the python console and inside a python plugin:

```
    raster = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()#.clone() # also tried with a new instance 
    raster.dataProvider().reloadData()
    raster.triggerRepaint()
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(raster.id())
```

Comment: Something I didn't mention is when you zoom in/out a few times, the layer is redrawn properly

Comment: There's an [edit] button beneath your question for revising it with any additional information/clarifications.